# se destruyen automaticamente las variables de sesion en laravel

Tags: laravel

hola tengo un proyecto en laravel que lo instale en un hosting compartido, este proyecto de manera local funciona correctamente, pero al subirlo al hosting, han dejado de funcionar las variables de sesión o se pierden de forma inmediata al enviar un formulario. por ejemplo tengo una función:

```
public function create(){   
/Session::put('mi_variable','hola mundo');    
dd(\Session::get('mi_variable')); // Aquí si se imprime.   
return view('vistas.formulario'); 
} 
public function imprimirVariableDeSesion(){   dd(\Session::get('mi_variable'));//Aquí no se imprime. 
}
```

cuando se muestra el formulario que retorno en la primera función y me envía a la función `(imprimirVariableDeSesion)` , dicha variable ya no se muestra

Comment: estas manteniendo la session en cada pagina?

Comment: se supone que si, es un framework que no necesitas mantener la sesión en cada página. Lo hace de forma automática.

Comment: esto solo me pasa en el hosting compartido, pero localmente funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me paso una vez 
El problema al parecer es q el host ha puesto el session_path en un directorio que ya no existe, por lo que no se guardan los datos de session.

Puedes arreglarlo de dos formar

1. Poniendo en cada uno de tus scripts 
    ini_set('session.save_path','ALGUN_PATH_QUE_SEPAS_EXISTA');
2. Hablando con tu servidor de host del problema y esperar que lo solucione :D